# Webform submission vs email submit

Tags: webforms, emails, forms

I have same webform in three different languages. In First two languages, after submit, page is refreshed, and confirmation message shown: "Your email was sent".

But in third language, after submitting, drupal redirects to

```
/node/14/done?sid=17
```

And confirmation message is shown as following:

```
Thank you, your submission has been received.
```

How can i force my third language webform, to do same thing as webforms in previous two languages? Webform/email settings are same for every webform.